# c++ map after assigning it to end(), it still execute one more iteration

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have the follow code,

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::map<int, int> test_m;
    test_m[1] = 1;
    test_m[2] = 2;
    test_m[3] = 3;
    test_m[4] = 4;
    test_m[7] = 7;
    test_m[8] = 8;
    auto it2 = test_m.find(2);
    auto it7 =test_m.find(7);
    auto it_end = test_m.end();
    for (auto it = it2; it!=test_m.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
        if (it->second == 3) {
            it = test_m.end();
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting:

```
2
3
```

But instead I am getting

```
2
3
8
```

May I know why?

Comment: Your program exhibits undefined behavior. You are effectively doing `it = test_m.end(); ++it;` , trying to increment the iterator past the end. Why not just `break` out of the loop?

Comment: You have undefined behavior since you set the iterator to `end()` and then incremented it.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are assigning `it = test_m.end()` inside the loop, but this assignment does not actually terminate the loop. Instead, it simply assigns a new value to the loop variable `it`, which is then incremented at the end of each iteration.

To terminate the loop, you can use a `break` statement. For example:

```cpp
for (auto it = it2; it != test_m.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl;
    if (it->second == 3) {
        break;  // Terminate the loop
    }
}
```

This will cause the loop to terminate when the value of `it->second` is equal to 3, resulting in the output you expect.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that iterating past end is undefined behaviour, even without dereferencing `it`.